# When does a price change occur in other countries?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, in-app-subscription

I have a question concerning a recurring subscription price change. When I schedule a price change does it go into effect at the same time in all countries or does it go into effect at 12:00 AM in each country's timezone?

Example: I schedule a price change for July 12. I live in the United States, I assume this price change will occur around 12:00 AM my time. Let's say a user is in France and the time there is 9 AM. Will the new price be made available at that time or will the App Store wait until it is 12:00 AM France time to enact the new price?

Answer (score 0):

Answer from Apple Support. There is no guarantee when the price change will occur, other than it will occur that day. This means that if you set a price change for July 12, it will occur in each country at some point in the day according to that country's local timezone.